# Cannot call commit when using distributed transactions

Tags: java, transactions, weblogic, datasource, osb

This error occured when trying to call stored procedure from Oracle SQL using DBAdapter with WebLogic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some forums offered to change the datasource from XA to NonXA, and deselect the checkbox "Supports Global Transactions". I do that and got other error "Cannot call Connection.commit in distributed transaction". I've restarted the WebLogic server and thats it. Problem Solved. FYI :)